# How to search a log file in Linux and escape special characters like square brackets (i.e. [ and ])

Tags: linux, search, special-characters

How to search a log file in Linux and escape special characters like square brackets (i.e. `[` and `]`)

Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

I `less` the log file as per below:

```
less system001A.LOG
```

Once I am in the log, I then press `<` (i.e. the smaller-than sign), and then I press forward-slash (i.e.`/`) and type what I would like to search for:

```
/ERROR [section_NAME]
```

The problem is how to escape these brackets while I search? Because when I run this, it says no pattern/match is found, yet this in fact exists on the log.

Comment: you need to escape the special characters by a backslash character. Like: `/ERROR \[section_NAME\]`

Comment: Have you tried to use /ERROR \\[section_NAME\\]

Comment: No, that did not work. I tried that now.

Comment: If the logfile has coloured text in it, you will have issues matching any of that.

Answer (score 23):

The manual does mention you can switch off regular expression search for the whole search string by pressing `^R` (<kbd>CTRL+R</kbd>) after you press `/`.

Comment: @ninjaloop Accept this headache-preventing answer!

Answer (score -1):

If you have GNU regex on your system (re_compile_pattern is found in C lib), then the escape character is the usual backslash (`\`). However, there are many different regex engines that `less` may be using, depends on how it was compiled: https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/master/pattern.c#L25